# Unable to start fancontrol service, broken configuration file

Tags: 12.04, hardware, asus, services, fancontrol

I've recently been trying to get my fans automated on my Asus H87-Pro Motherboard. I have 3 additional fans to the CPU fan.

To do this, I had to add `nct6775` to '/etc/modules' for the purpose of starting the the appropriate module to read from the nuvoTon chip.
This all shows up fine in `sensors`.

My issue is, now that I want to control this with fancontrol, I can't seem to create an appropriate configuration file when I run `sudo pwmconfig`. I have identified my three fans as pwm ports 1,3 & 4.
Every time I want to start the service, using `sudo service fancontrol start` , I receive the error message:

```
* Not starting fancontrol, broken configuration file; please re-run pwmconfig.
```

My `/etc/fancontrol` config file is set up with:

```
# Configuration file generated by pwmconfig, changes will be lost
INTERVAL=10
DEVPATH=hwmon4=devices/platform/nct6775.656
DEVNAME=hwmon4=nct6791
FCTEMPS=hwmon4/pwm4=hwmon4/temp2_input hwmon4/pwm3=hwmon4/temp2_input hwmon4/pwm1=hwmon4/temp2_input
FCFANS=hwmon4/pwm4=hwmon4/fan4_input hwmon4/pwm3=hwmon4/fan3_input hwmon4/pwm1=hwmon4/fan1_input
MINTEMP=hwmon4/pwm4=30 hwmon4/pwm3=30 hwmon4/pwm1=30
MAXTEMP=hwmon4/pwm4=53 hwmon4/pwm3=53 hwmon4/pwm1=53
MINSTART=hwmon4/pwm4=45 hwmon4/pwm3=45 hwmon4/pwm1=60
MINSTOP=hwmon4/pwm4=0 hwmon4/pwm3=34 hwmon4/pwm1=34
MINPWM=hwmon4/pwm4=34 hwmon4/pwm3=0  hwmon4/pwm1=0
MAXPWM=hwmon4/pwm4=255 hwmon4/pwm3=255 hwmon4/pwm1=255
```

Any ideas? I'm probably doing something quite stupid, would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since having realized I've been working with the older 12.04 LTS Ubuntu, I've **updated** to 16.04.

{Note, by doing so, the error message changed if I tried `service fancontrol start` on 16.04:
`Job for fancontrol.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status fancontrol.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`
}

I don't believe this provided the solution, however when I tried the command `fancontrol --configure` {on the new 16.04, I hadn't done it before}, I was given feedback detailing the problem.

```
Error in configuration file (hwmon4/pwm4):
MINSTOP must be greater than or equal to MINPWM
```

It's a shame that I wasn't able to identify this. But that's how you learn! Fixing this, I was then able to start the fancontrol service with `service fancontrol start`.

Comment: I also had a small issue later with the device name changing. In 16.04 hwmon4 became the device hwmon3. This was just a small change in the config files.